# BJT DC biasing and amplification

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, bias, base

[image]

Does this part of the datasheet has to do with biasing and amplifying DC using BJT (TIP120)?

[[!tip120 datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MSq4.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MSq4.png)

Answer (score 0):

h_fe (or beta) specifies how much the output current (Ic) will change when the input current (Ib) is changed. No, it has not directly to do with biasing. Yes, it has to do with amplifying dc **current**.

Answer (score 0):

BJT current gain hFE varies between transistors, even transistors with the same part number. Therefore, a good design should ensure that hFE doesn't matter much.